# How to make journalctl recognize user-defined fields?

Tags: systemd, journalctl

Journalctl's [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html) says:

> New fields may freely be defined by applications, but a few fields
>   have special meaning.

However I don't see a way to actually introduce my own field that journalctl would recognize and allow filter on.

I tried many variations of the following to no avail:

```
echo 'FOO=12' | systemd-cat -t TestFields -p warning
```

journalctl doesn't see FOO field that I'm trying to add:

```
# journalctl -f -t TestFields
-- Logs begin at Wed 2018-11-28 16:08:31 UTC. --
Nov 28 16:29:10 2f79ab2701c9 TestFields[105]: FOO=12
```

in json format:

```
# journalctl -f -t TestFields -o json-pretty
{
    "__CURSOR" : "s=95d756f74cc14c25b5d6a6c86e2d3dd4;i=31b;b=c2286470c74849db84c4a2b458276561;m=4686eb5305;t=57bbc10de8aab;x=8ea14ded83dc4684",
    "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" : "1543422550641323",
    "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "302911279877",
    "_BOOT_ID" : "c2286470c74849db84c4a2b458276561",
    "_UID" : "0",
    "_GID" : "0",
    "_MACHINE_ID" : "70406ad7f5774a17a5f1cbbaf5f4455e",
    "_HOSTNAME" : "2f79ab2701c9",
    "PRIORITY" : "4",
    "_CAP_EFFECTIVE" : "3fffffffff",
    "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "0",
    "_TRANSPORT" : "stdout",
    "_COMM" : "cat",
    "_EXE" : "/usr/bin/cat",
    "_CMDLINE" : "/bin/cat",
    "_STREAM_ID" : "7bf67dfa7ff846429fea8092f40a34f7",
    "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "TestFields",
    "MESSAGE" : "FOO=12",
    "_PID" : "105"
}
```

and finally filtering yields no result:

```
# journalctl FOO=12 -t TestFields
-- No entries --
```

for comparison:

```
# journalctl _PID=105 -t TestFields
-- Logs begin at Wed 2018-11-28 16:08:31 UTC, end at Wed 2018-11-28 16:29:10 UTC. --
Nov 28 16:29:10 2f79ab2701c9 TestFields[105]: FOO=12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is exploring this path, the answer is no, you can't do that. Consider using structured logs where you can add whatever fields you want.